# How to get sender info from double-tap GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func BetPop(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var BetPopVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BetPop") as VC3
    self.presentViewController(BetPopVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is connected to multiple buttons in `VC1: ViewController` and presents `VC3: ViewController`

In `prepareForSegue` I'd like to pass string data to notify `VC3` which of the many `VC1 UIButtons` called the action. I have declared this as `var betSource = ""` in `VC3`

For previous string passes I used something like this in `prepareForSegue`

```
let BVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC3
    BVC.source = segue.identifier!
```

But those previous segues were produced using `Storyboard` in which i could name the `segue.identifier`.

**1.Is there a way to do segue via double-tap on `Storyboard`?**

and/or

**2.Can I put something like...**

```
BVC.betSource = (title of UIButton pressed or VC-presenting-UIButton)
```

**in my `@IBAction func BetPop`?**

Comment: You have not created a segue, so there is no identifier. What you're doing is a manual presentation. A segue is a storyboard feature, it makes no sense to say you're creating one programmatically. You can invoke one programmatically (with performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:), but you can't create one.

Comment: okay ty, i adjusted OP question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use tap gesture recognizers, it would be best to attach them to labels rather than buttons. You can setup a segue directly from a tap gesture recognizer in IB, and it will be passed in as the sender argument to prepareForSegue:sender:. You can get the view that the tapper was attached to with its view property. You can then use that to get the text of the label or its tag that you can use to distinguish which label was double tapped.

Comment: "You can setup a segue directly from a tap gesture recognizer in IB, and it will be passed in as the sender argument to prepareForSegue:sender" solved my issue, ty.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually creating a segue, per se, you're sort of simply invoking the navigation. Based on your code, you'd most likely need to do something like this:

```
@IBAction func BetPop(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var BetPopVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BetPop") as VC3
    let buttonThatWasDoubleTapped = sender.view as UIButton //assuming you hooked the gesture recognizer to a UIButton in order to handle double taps
    BetPopVC.betSource = buttonThatWasDoubleTapped.titleLabel.text
    self.presentViewController(BetPopVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As for your second question, it looks like you're creating a gesture recognizer to invoke your VC3. Simply setting this parameter will launch the event on double taps.

```
myGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
```

Comment: okay but how do i code the "source"? i need it to = UIButton title/identifier, because multiple buttons present same VC3

Comment: That's what's strange about your code. You are saying the user is tapping on UIButtons to invoke VC3... so why is your sender a UITapGestureRecognizer and not a UIButton? If they are tapping on a UIButton, you can simply get the sender.titleLabel.text for the button title.

Comment: do you know of another way to produce segue via storyboard that is invoked only by double-tap? And yes they tap a UIButton that has a UITapGestureRecognizer overlayed

Comment: and Yes I've already set GestureRecognizer = 2 taps, Im asking if i could forego all this by someway to do this through Storyboard so that it is a 'true' segue.

Comment: So you want to double tap on a button and cause it to go to VC3? In that case, you should use the gesture recognizer like you are. You can convert sender.view into a UIButton and get the title from that to know which button was tapped.

Comment: I used a work-around of creating `storyboard` segue from multiple gestureRecognizer and passing strings based on segue.identifier...  But this suggestion sounds more optimal and generic...I would love to know how to **"convert sender.view into a UIButton and get the title"**

Comment: let title = (sender.view as UIButton).labelTitle.text - something like that. Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: yes but using 9 gestureRecognizer...and I don't know if this makes my code sub-optimal on memory or CPU. I also like cleaner, generic code. I will try this^^^^^. ty

Comment: `let title = (sender.view as UIButton).labelTitle.text` in `VC1` `prepareForSegue` produces ERROR: 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'view'

Comment: prepareForSegue's sender is not a UIButton. That's fine, you got it working with storyboard segues so I think you're on the right track.

Comment: yes...but its using 9 different GestureRecognizers...does this slow down the app or make it too bulky. I plan to make more VC's with 8,7,6,5,4,3 and 2 buttons

Comment: Do your buttons do anything on single tap or only on double tap? If you only do double tap then I would skip using buttons and just use Views (but would work the same on buttons, as well). Attach ONE gesture recognizer to 9 views and use the function in the answer here to get which view was double tapped.

Comment: They use single, double and touch up outside.

Comment: Cool, then you are currently attaching a single gesture recognizer to all of the UIButtons to handle the double taps? In the prepareForSegue invoked by the gesture recognizer I don't think you can know what button was double tapped. So I would remove that segue and instead do your original code where you are handling the double tap action yourself but just use my code above to figure out what button was tapped. Ignore this if you got everything working already some other way, this is just a recommendation.